# SQL compile error trying to load data from .csv

Tags: sql, database, csv, db2, ibm-data-studio

I have a simple SQL query that is suppose to get the data from .csv file and insert or update the data in the table

```
import from /home/AssetAllocation/labels.csv of del insert_update into labels
```

I am trying to run the query in IBM Data Studio but am getting a compile error on the import, of and del.  How do I fix query to get no compile errors?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message(s)? That might lake it easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute the `IMPORT` command directly within Data Studio, because `IMPORT` is a DB2 CLP command, not an SQL statement.

If you must use Data Studio, then the data file you want to import must reside on the database server.  There are 2 ways to do this:

1. You can use it with the `ADMIN_CMD()` [stored procedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html) (this requires that the file you want to load reside on the database server itself, though).
2. You can right-click on a table name in Data Studio and click the "Load" option and then choose "With Import Utility".  This will actually open an `ssh` session to your server to perform the import.

If you have the DB2 Data Server Client on your PC this may be the easiest way, as you can start a DB2 Command Line Processor (CLP) window and execute the `IMPORT` command that you were trying to execute to begin with.